# Colors a plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have array of points in MATLAB , and i want to draw them all in the **same color** but with **different degree**, so the first point will be **dark blue** and then the second point must be **lighter** than the first point and so on.

example:

```
   a = [1:100];
   plot(a,a,'*');

   then point (1,1) will be very dark red ,,, and point (100,100) will be very very light red
```

can i do that in MATLAB with a large size arrays ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [scatter plot](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) with color arguments and a colormap:

```
x = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
y = sin(x);
a = [1:100];
dotsize=25;
clridx = 1:100;
scatter(x,y,dotsize,clridx,'fill');

% create the colormap:
color1=[25 25 112]/255; % Midnight Blue
color2=[135 206 250]/255;% Light Sky Blue
numcolors = numel(clridx);
% create the gradients
clrmap = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(a,b)linspace(a,b,numcolors )',color1,color2,'uni',false));

% set the colormap
colormap(clrmap);
```

[image: scatter color gradient]

or if it becomes too slow, you can try this alternative: [matlab: scatter plots with high number of datapoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302623/matlab-scatter-plots-with-high-number-of-datapoints/13304227#13304227)